# Using class file in different android project eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse

i'm new to eclipse and programming but have a university project i need help with.
I created an Android Application Project that locate your position using GPS (the code found online actually and works perfectly).

This is my MainActivity.java :

```
    package com.example.locationfromgps;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements LocationListener{

LocationManager locationManager ;
String provider;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Getting LocationManager object
    locationManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    // Creating an empty criteria object
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();

    // Getting the name of the provider that meets the criteria
    provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);

    if(provider!=null && !provider.equals("")){

        // Get the location from the given provider
        Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 20000, 1, this);

        if(location!=null)
            onLocationChanged(location);
        else
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Location can't be retrieved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }else{
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No Provider Found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    // Getting reference to TextView tv_longitude
    TextView tvLongitude = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_longitude);

    // Getting reference to TextView tv_latitude
    TextView tvLatitude = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_latitude);

    // Setting Current Longitude
    tvLongitude.setText("Longitude:" + location.getLongitude());

    // Setting Current Latitude
    tvLatitude.setText("Latitude:" + location.getLatitude() );
}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}
}
```

The project will generate class files as BuildConfig.class MainActivity.class and R.class.
I created a different new android project, added these class files using Configure Build Path -> libraries -> add class folder, which works and are visible in Referenced libraries.
Now my goal and question is if i can run this new project and make it show me a location without adding the actual java code (the whole MainActivity.java) but only by referencing it to the class files.
Can i do this? and if yes how to ?

PS: i actually tested a small Java project that only shows an integer; then added its class file into another java project and ran this new project and it worked but this seems more complicated when using a complex android app project.

Comment: make the 1st a library project. you can refer the same in your project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do two things

- If you dont want the java code, Make a jar from the project you want to use and put it in the libs folder
- Mark one project as library project and use it